# StarterSTS issue additional claims

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs2.0, adfs, sts-securitytokenservice

Does anyone know how to issue additional claims from StarterSTS by Dominic (Codeplex). I currently am getting only Login Time Instance and the Authentication Type which is password. Is there some config file i can edit or Code i need to insert to provide additional claims to the user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can in StarterSTS, but if you note on the project it says:-

> IMPORTANT
>   StarterSTS has been discontinued. The sources will stay up here for educational purposes. Please use my new project IdentityServer (http://identityserver.codeplex.com) from now on.

IdentityServer does support additional claims. You add the claims using the user profile - it's very easy to do so I would recommend you upgrade to this if possible.

I can't see the source for starterSTS so I'm not sure if it supports this feature. You can find [Identity Server V2 here](http://thinktecture.github.com/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/)

Comment: It sure does support, but has to be coded here is the link https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/issues/84